# What verb is omitted in this sentence?　「この船を引き上げよう**って**ヤツは何者だ」

Tags: grammar, particle-って

しかし 、この船を引き上げよう**って**ヤツは何者だ
after this って, im thinking about 言う or してる, which one is actually the one?

If it's 言う, does it have the literal meaning here as in "to say", or is it just the classic という?

Can you provide another type of this volitional + って + noun sentence please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since no one else has responded at all, I'll turn my off-the-cuff comment into an actual answer post.

Just my quick-and-dirty parsing of this sentence suggests that this って is equivalent to the generic という, which is kinda like English coordinating pronouns like "who" or "that" or "which". *"A guy **who** would try to raise up this ship,..."*